# is the Calendarific JSON format fully defined anywhere?

Tags: java, json, calendar

I'm looking at using the Calendarific API (https://calendarific.com/api-documentation) for working out working days in various territories, and the JSON response is useful, but I can't find a full definition of the fields in the API. Specifically I need to know all the possible types of observance in the 'type' field.
I've not been able to find a full spec anywhere. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has been updated to show what the types of holiday mean. You can find the updated information here: By default, the API returns all holidays. Below is the list of holiday types supported by the API and this is how to reference them.

`national` - Returns public, federal and bank holidays

`local` - Returns local, regional and state holidays

`religious` - Return religious holidays: buddhism, christian, hinduism, muslim, etc

`observance` - Observance, Seasons, Times

Ref: https://calendarific.com/api-documentation?v=2